# Flutter how to change background and text for a specific section of an image?

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating an App in flutter and needed some ideas on how to go about doing  this,

I am adding pdf - png images to my app which has Arabic text and need a way to change the text of an image. If an image has so much text I want to go to a certain line in a text and swipe to the right and change background and text. What widget should I use? Or how should I go about doing this? swipe to the right I want it to highlight English text with a nice background and swipe to the left back to Arabic. I am using the flutter framework and am stuck on how to go about doing this?

and how to do it code-wise... will I need to add dimensions per each line?

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:Quran_highlighter/main.dart';
import 'package:system_shortcuts/system_shortcuts.dart';
import 'package:Quran_highlighter/Widgets/NavDrawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:zoom_widget/zoom_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

//  onPanEnd: (details) {
//       if (swipeLeft) {
//         handleSwipeLeft();
//       } else
//         handleSwipeRight();
//     },
//     onPanUpdate: (details) {
//       if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
//         swipeLeft = false;
//       } else {
//         //print("Dragging in -X direction");
//         swipeLeft = true;
//       }
//     },
Future main() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
  runApp(new Aliflaammeem());
}

class Aliflaammeem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AliflaammeemState createState() => _AliflaammeemState();
}

class _AliflaammeemState extends State<Aliflaammeem> {
  // Widget body(BuildContext context) {
  //   if(MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait)
  //   {
  //     return portrait();
  //   }
  //   else {
  //     return landscape();
  //   }
  // }
// landscapeLeft
// landscapeRight
// portraitDown
// portraitUp
  double value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    value = 0.0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // appBar: AppBar(
    //   title: Text('Para 1, Pg2'),
    //   backgroundColor: Colors.teal[400],

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    return Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
      if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
        print("right swipe english");
        setState(() {
          //  highlightColor: Colors.green,
          // textColor: Colors.white,
          new Text(
            "In The Name of Allah, the Benificient, The Mericiful",
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
          );
//               // fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
          // fontFamily: "Roboto"),
          // value = 2.1;
        });
      } else if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
        print("left swipe arabic");
        setState(() {
          //  highlightColor: Colors.green,
          // textColor: Colors.white,
          new Text(
            "In The Name of Allah,The Mericiful",
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
          );
          // value= 0.1;
        });
        new Container(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        // child: Zoom(
                        //   height:1800,
                        //   width: 1800,
                        child: SafeArea(
                            top: true,
                            bottom: true,
                            right: true,
                            left: true,
                            child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage('test/assets/quranpg0.png'),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover))))));
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect swipe to right and left , you can use GestureDetector .

> Declare a boolean to know whether its a left or right swipe.

```
bool swipeLeft=false;
```

and inside your scaffold or wherever you are writing this code, wrap GestureDetector around your child widget.

```
child: GestureDetector(

        onPanEnd: (details) {
          if (swipeLeft) {
            handleSwipeLeft();
          } else
            handleSwipeRight();
        },
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
            swipeLeft = false;
          } else {
            //print("Dragging in -X direction");
            swipeLeft = true;
          }
        },
        child: Container(
              child: PDFPngImage(),
        )
  ),
```

Whenever user starts swiping on screen, onPanUpdate is called with details of user interaction.
From the details, you can extract whether its right swipe or left swipe

```
 onPanUpdate: (details) {
          if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
            //it means , user is swiping towards right
            //hence set bool variable to false.
            swipeLeft = false;
          } 
        }
```

And when swiping ends completely, onPanEnd is called , hence check the status of bool variable, whether it was a swipe left or right and update UI accordingly.

Hope this is clear and helpful!!

@Edit: Similar Complete Code related to what you want to implement in particular.
Try following a similar approach and implement it. I hope this is clear!

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  var myText = "";
  var image;
  var pageIndex = 0;
  var numberOfOnBoardScreens = 3;
  var swipeLeft = false;

  var data = [
    [
      'assets/images/urdu.png',
      'Text in urdu',
    ],
    [
      'assets/images/English.png',
      'English translation',
    ],
    [
      'assets/images/french.png',
      'Translation in french',
    ]
  ];
  handleClick(direction) {
    print('handle click :$direction');
    if (direction == -1) //moving left
    {
      if (pageIndex > 0) {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex -= 1;
        });
      }
    } else if (numberOfOnBoardScreens - 1 > pageIndex) {
      setState(() {
        pageIndex += 1;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
          //onHorizontalDragEnd: handleClick(1),
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            if (swipeLeft) {
              handleClick(1);
            } else
              handleClick(-1);
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
              swipeLeft = false;
            } else {
              //print("Dragging in -X direction");
              swipeLeft = true;
            }
          },
          child: TestPageScreenWidgetState(
            image: data[pageIndex][0],
            myText: data[pageIndex][1],
          )),
    );
  }
}

class TestPageScreenWidgetState extends StatelessWidget {
  final myText;
  var image;
  var currentScreen = 1;

  TestPageScreenWidgetState({
    this.image,
    this.myText,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top,
        ),
        Image.asset(
          image,
        ),
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 10, 90, 60),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                '$myText',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can i change background ... like lets say if i swipe to the right on an image , can i change the background and text? without adding a button

Comment: Yes , you can rebuild your whole UI ,by using setState() by changing your Stateless widget to a stateful widget . When you detect right swipe using GestureDetector as mentioned above , just call setState and change the image and text.

Comment: Hi Sajjan I did update my code with stateful widget and set state ... but every time I run it the image is not displaying ... what iw ant to do is ... per each line I want to swipe to right - and have the background and text change to English and if I swipe to lett that effect goes away ... please help

Comment: I will update my answer with code related to what you want, refer to it, and try implementing it.

Comment: Thank you I did try that but no luck I got a index error kept trying to fix it took good amount of days still no luck

Comment: Index error might be because you are mentioning an index that is beyond the size of your list size. Check that. It's pretty much the working code, try you will get it.